# What is V.A.T.S in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3, terminology

What is V.A.T.S in Fallout 3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the system in which you can pause the action a take aim at specific body parts, with known percentage of hitting them, and with each action costing a specific amount of "action points" (AP).

It stands for "Vault-Tec Assisted Targeting system", but mostly it

- Gives a more cinematic feel when using it, due to the slow-motion action sequence after choosing a target.
- Makes the game closer to earlier, turn-based Fallout games in which you could target specific body parts with known percentages, paying with action points, in a very similar way.
- Gives the game a more RPG-ish, tactical feel than a typical shooter.
- Makes the game easier / less stressful.

You can read more about it on [Wikia's Fallout](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_Assisted_Targeting_System), [Gamespy](http://planetfallout.gamespy.com/wiki/Fallout_3_VATS) and even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_3#V.A.T.S.).

Comment: You didn't think my answer was good enough, did you? =o)

Comment: @Juan sorry man, I started it before you posted yours and I didn't click the "update" bar :(

Comment: @Juan, @Oak > http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: It was a joke though

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/49787#49787 :)

Comment: @GnomeSlice, @BlueRaja, Problem, what problem?  I got fast good answers.

Comment: No, I know, I was just pointing out...   All in good fun, right?

Comment: Just a note to explicitly say that VATS also lets you distribute your shots between multiple enemies, not just the body parts of one enemy.

Comment: And I know this is subject is kind of dead, but I think that VATS also does heavier damage/use on your weapons that not in VATS - mode

Answer (score 6):

It's the Vault-Tec Assisted Targeting System

See [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_Assisted_Targeting_System)

> The Vault-Tec Assisted Targeting System, or V.A.T.S., is a queuing system for Fallout 3 and Fallout: New Vegas, inspired partly by the ability to shoot specific body parts in the turn-based combat system of Fallout and Fallout 2. V.A.T.S. is also used for a cinematic combat experience.

Answer (score -1):

Vault Tec Assisted Targeting System

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it adds nothing to the discussion.